# Responsive design issue on the timeline page on the mobile screen

Tags: bug, design, timeline, responsive-design

When viewing any timeline page on a mobile screen, the header banner is missing while scrolling to the right-hand side in landscape and portrait mode.

Sample timeline page: https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/382019/timeline

[image: With header]
[image: Without header]

Google Chrome: 106.0.5249.79
Operating System: Android 12

Comment: That's the way it's *supposed* to render if content stretches out of the bounds of the page. The only legitimate solution to this problem is finding a way to responsively display that table so that it doesn't require a scrollbar. Making the other containers stretch to the size of the content introduces other problems to the layout.

Comment: @animuson Can't the scrollbar be for the table only instead of the entire page?

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine That would also be a good interim compromise. I don't believe it'd be very hard to do in this particular case, by wrapping it in `<div class="s-table-container">` container, assuming there are no other side-effects. But it wouldn't fix anything for other situations where content is too wide for the page.

Comment: Is disabling the page for portrait mode a good option? I don't think so...

Comment: I think it would be great if SE used short forms for some stuff like "answer", "comment", "history" in portrait mode.

Comment: BTW, what do you exactly mean by header? You mean the blue MSE logo bar?

Comment: The situation in flags page is much worse :(